# SIM 900: Error 604 Stack Busy

Tags: stack, arduino, ip-address, gsm, gprs

I'm using a SIM 900 GPRS Shield for Arduino for sending data using HTTP command; sometime when I use the command

```
AT+HTTPACTION=1
```

I receive error code 604, that mean Stack Busy.
Someone know what is the problem?

If I reset the board I receive the same this error; I note that if I turn off and turn on the GPRS board, so that I receive a new IP address, the error does not occur, so it's like if the old IP address is "blocked"; why?

Comment: It's not the new IP address that solves your problem.  It is because you have re-started the protocol stack when you switch the board off and on.  Probably this does more than a simple "reset".  The error is in the message - the protocol stack is busy.  Do other commands pass?

Comment: no, no other commands pass

Comment: What is the command that makes the protocol stack hang? (probably the first command that doesn't return an answer)  Can you report it to the manufacturer as a bug?  Possibly a firmware upgrade would fix it.

Comment: this was the report:
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","myaddress.com"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION:0,604,0

Comment: It looks as though you didn't get an answer to AT+HTTPPARA="URL","myaddress.com" .  Have you tried waiting for an answer before you send more AT commands?

Comment: i'm waiting for 10 seconds.. i could try to wait more time and using a timeout for avoiding an infinite wait